# Discriminate goal in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coqide

I have two conditions for nat numbers:

```
H:  a < b
H1: b < a
```

How to discriminate goal?
Does exist any tactics for < ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lia`:

```
From Coq Require Import Lia.

Goal forall a b, a < b -> b < a -> False.
  lia.
Qed.
```

You can learn more about `lia` and other decision procedures for arithmetic [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/micromega.html#coq:tacn.lia).

Answer (score 0):

For reference, doing a manual proof is not so difficult in this case:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Lemma foo a b (a_lt_b : a < b) : b < a -> False.
Proof. by rewrite ltnNge (ltnW a_lt_b). Qed.
```